# How to get position from markers for tracking? (Android Mapbox)

Tags: android, position, mapbox, tracking, marker

Here is the problem:

I want to show the user the best route to reach a marker after the user presses a button inside the infoWindow. The problem is, I can't get the marker's Location data due to some problem with **Latlng** and **Position** classes. (I am using the Mapbox example to get the route, so I need two Position values)

So basically, I need to update the variable *Destination* with the marker's position by clicking a button inside the custom infowindow. Yet I have no idea how can I do that even though going through a lot on searching Google and Stack Overflow. Can someone help me? (Cammack!) Thanks a bunch for the help!

---

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //...

    // Origem: Rodoviaria
    final Position origin = Position.fromCoordinates(-47.882645, -15.794082);
    // Destino: Reitoria
    final Position destination = Position.fromCoordinates(-47.866611, -15.762604);

    //...

        mapboxMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MapboxMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                @Nullable
                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(@NonNull Marker marker) {
                    //...

                    final Marker marcador = marker;

                    botaoIr = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.botaoIr);
                    botaoIr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            //I have been trying the method below, but I am having trouble with LatLng and Position classes!
                            //LatLng ponto = marcador.getPosition();
                            //destination = new Position(ponto.getLongitude(),ponto.getLatitude());

                            try {
                                getRoute(origin, destination);
                            } catch (ServicesException servicesException) {
                                servicesException.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
    //...
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a position call `fromCoordinates()`.

```
destination = Position.fromCoordinates(ponto.getLongitude(),ponto.getLatitude());
```

Comment: Thanks, I was close enough but that worked!
Can I ask for a suggestion? I need to remove the marker before adding that new marker, I know I can use mapboxMap.removeMarker(marker), but I need to initialize the Position variable before doing such thing, do you know a good suggestion on the value I could initialize said variable? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question but you can try checking if the marker is null and if it isn't then you know it is on the map and can be removed.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, but I mean I need a method to clean the route and the markers that was being shown, like using a mapboxMap.clear() method, but only erasing the route that was found and the new markers that has been added. Otherwise, every time I click on that button, it will add the new marker and the new route but it won't erase the previous one, do you know a method that cleans such thing? Thanks again Cammace! I owe you one!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all annotations on your map, you can call "removeAnnotations()" on your MapBoxMap-Instance:

```
mapboxMap.removeAnnotations();
```

..or you can call "remove()" on any annotation from MapBox itself (Polygon, Polyline or Marker)

```
Polygon pol = new Polygon();
pol.remove();
```

If it's still existing and you just want to change & update an annotation, call "updatePolygon()", "updateMarker" or "updatePolyline() like this:

```
mapboxMap.updatePolygon(myPolgonInstance);
mapboxMap.updateMarker(myMarkerInstance);
...
```

Comment: Hmm, the ideas are pretty good but I am having some problem in doing so. I need to remove the previous markers created when I clicked on said button. Because every time I click on a new button, it creates another set of markers as well as a polyline through the map, yet the previous one does still show up. But the problem is, I can't do `marker.remove();` as it does not show up for me. I could try `mapboxMap.removeMarker(marker)` but I can't do it either because it does not allow MarkerOptions. Can you please help me? Thanks!